# Problem with add-ins excel2latex

Tags: tables, excel, excel2latex

I would like to convert my excel table to latex code using the add-ins **Excel2latex.xla** downloaded from the website CTAN. I followed the necessary steps to add this option to excel file wich is copying the **excel2latex.xla** into Microsoft Office Addins folder. On my PC the path is : **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\ADDINS**.

After I activited the add-ins in Excel, I colsed the Software and I re-open it again, then I didn't find the add-ins option in the upper right hand corner.

[image]

Can you please tell me what should I do about it.

Comment: I think maybe [this](https://professor-excel.com/prevent-excel-add-in-disappear/) will help.

Answer (score 1):

This works with windows 7 and windows 10, excel 2013 (Office15)

Open excel File> Options > AddIns (in the left menu)

[image: zz]

Press Go ... then Browse ,,, it will open the directory  `C:\Users\<my user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`

If `Excel2LaTeX.xla` is there, click to select, or put the file in that directory and then click it.

Select Excel2Latex in the list of Add-Ins available and click OK.

[image: xx]

The icon for Convert a Table to LaTex will appear in the ADD-INS of the ribbon.

You might need to Customize the ribbon to add a new tab.

[image: yy]

[image: mm]

Comment: Thank you for your illustrations, I did all what you have mentioned before,. However, I still not have the Tool of Add-Ins in the tool Bar. By the way, I use Excel 2016.